# code not working in angular js

Tags: angularjs

```
//login.html

<div ng-controller="loginController">
<form action="/" id="myLogin">
    User Name:<input type="text" ng-model="uname" /> <br />
    Password: <input type="password" ng-model="passwd"/> <br />
    <button type="button"  ng-click="submit()">login</button>
</form>
</div>

//controller.js

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html'
    })
    .when('/employeeReg', {
        templateUrl: 'employeeReg.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/'
    })
});

app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        if ($scope.uname == 'admin' && $scope.passwd == 'admin') {
            $location.path('employeeReg.html');
        } else {
            alert('login failed');
        }
    };
});
```

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBdze.png)

i very new to angular js, this sample code is for just login page but when i open index page nothing is visible, it should redirect to login page.any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Where is your index page code?

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually i have added screen shot of code but it is not showing here..https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBdze.png in this link index code is available..

Comment: Where is the routing for index page inside your controller

Comment: You don't have anything in index.html. In controller.js you are redirecting to login page by default. So, it is showing login.html page

Comment: it is not redirecting to login page.it is showing index.html.i want to redirect to login page so what changes i need to make?

Comment: Can you see the console for errors

Comment: no errors in console

Answer (score 0):

Try including the angular first:

```
<script src='JS/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='JS/angular-route.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Yes but the order matters.

Answer (score 0):

Made plunker. Looks like working

https://plnkr.co/edit/kHXK54?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngSanitize']);

app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
           .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller  : 'loginController'
        })
        .when('/employee', {
            templateUrl: 'employee.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo:'/'
        })
    }]);

app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        if ($scope.uname == 'admin' && $scope.passwd == 'admin') {
            $location.path('/employee');
        } else {
            alert('login failed');
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: yes i checked, i think that is different case, in first page resolve link is there but in my case i want to display login page when index page is opened